# Fast way to Insert rows into DB?

Tags: c#, optimization, insert, parallel-processing, tibco

I'm looping thorugh the rows of a dataset and inserting it into an active-space environment (by tibco, its an in-memory db). This is how i'm doing it.

Is there a faster way to go about this?

I was thinking of partitioning the rows and then paralleling each partition, but i have no clue if that will make it faster.

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach(
    dataSet.Tables[0].Rows,
    currRow =>
    {
        var tuple = Com.Tibco.As.Space.Tuple.Create();

        for (int i = 0; i < currRow.Values.Length; i++)
        {
            if (currRow.Values[i] != null)
            {
                var k = ConvertToAny(currRow.Values[i].ToString());

                if (k.GetType().IsEquivalentTo(typeof(DateTime)))
                {
                    tuple.Put(dataSet.Tables[0].ColumnNames[i], (DateTime)k);
                }
                else if (k.GetType().IsEquivalentTo(typeof(double)))
                {
                    tuple.Put(dataSet.Tables[0].ColumnNames[i], (double)k);
                }
                else
                {
                    tuple.Put(dataSet.Tables[0].ColumnNames[i], k.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
        try
        {
            inSpace_.Put(tuple);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
    }
);
```

I'm thinking of batching it at around 1000 at a time, if someone can please help :(

**EDIT:**

List tuplesToAdd = new List();
            for (int i = 0; i < dataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Length; i++)
            {
                var tuple = Com.Tibco.As.Space.Tuple.Create();

```
            for (int j = 0; j < dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[i].Values.Length; j++)
            {
                if (dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[i].Values[j] != null)
                {
                    var k = ConvertToAny(dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[i].Values[j].ToString());
                    if (k is DateTime)
                    {
                        tuple.Put(dataSet.Tables[0].ColumnNames[j], (DateTime)k);
                    }
                    else if (k is Double)
                    {
                        tuple.Put(dataSet.Tables[0].ColumnNames[j], (Double)k);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        tuple.Put(dataSet.Tables[0].ColumnNames[j], k.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }

            tuplesToAdd.Add(tuple);

            if (i % 100000 == 0 || i == dataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Length - 1)
            {

                ThreadStart TUPLE_WORKER = delegate
                {
                    inSpace_.PutAll(tuplesToAdd);
                };
                new Thread(TUPLE_WORKER).Start();
                tuplesToAdd.Clear();
            }
        }
```

There's my new way of trying to do it (by batching)

Comment: Does the database engine support any sort of bulk import method?  Are you running this on a machine with lots of cores?  Just naively throwing a `Parallel.ForEach` around row inserts is adding a lot of complexity to the problem with likely not that much gain.

Comment: FYI - you don't need to include tags in your question title (`C#` in this case).

Comment: That's bad as table locks may happen when you are trying to insert data into the same table at the same time. Use Bulk insert in SQL.

Comment: Yes it does include a bulk import. i would have to create a list of tuples and jut put inspace_.PutAll(tuples)

Comment: @AzharKhorasany it's thread safe according to the developers guide

Comment: @Ramie: Thread-safety is not free.  Using multiple threads like that may slow it down due to extra synchronization work.

Comment: @SLaks so parallel doesn't always speed it up eh? especially in this case??

Comment: Correct.  `Parallel` is not magic.  It will primarily help for "delightfully parallel" problems which involve unrelated computations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not certain, but it looks like you could avoid the `ToString` in your conversion code. That is, rather than:

```
var k = ConvertToAny(currRow.Values[i].ToString());

if (k.GetType().IsEquivalentTo(typeof(DateTime)))
```

Can be replaced by ...

```
var k = currRow.Values[i];
if (k is DateTime)
{
    tuple.Put(dataSet.Tables[0].ColumnNames[i], (DateTime)k);
}
```

That should save you converting to string and then back.

**Added in response to comments**

First, your `ConvertToAny` is unnecessary. The item in `currRow.Values[i]` is already the right type. You just don't know what type it is. Unless you're saying that it could be the string representation of a `DateTime` or a `Double`. If the type is *already* a double, for example, then there's no reason to convert to string, parse, and then convert back. That is, the following two bits of code do the same thing:

```
object o = 3.14;
var k = ConvertToAny(o.ToString());
if (k.GetType.IsEquivalentTo(typeof(double))
```

and

```
object o = 3.14;
if (o is double)
```

The only difference is that the second will be much faster.

However, if you have

```
object o = "3.14";
```

and you want that to be converted to `double`, then you'll have to do the conversion.

Your code that batches things has to lock the list when adding and updating. Otherwise you will corrupt it. I would suggest:

```
lock (tuplesToAdd)
{
    tuplesToAdd.Add(tuple);
    if ((tuplesToAdd.Count % 10000) == 0)
    {
        // push them all to the database.
        inspace_.PutAll(tuplesToAdd);
        tuplesToAdd.Clear();
    }
}
```

And when you're all done (i.e. the `Parallel.Foreach` is done):

```
if (tuplesToAdd.Count > 0)
{
    // push the remaining items
}
```

Now, if you want to avoid blocking all of the threads during the update, you can get a little creative.

First, create two objects that you can lock on:

```
private object lockObject = new Object();
private object pushLock = new Object();
```

Create that right after you create the `tuplesToAdd` list. Then, when you want to add an item:

```
Monitor.Enter(lockObject); // acquires the lock
tuplesToAdd.Add(tuple);
if (tuplesToAdd.Count == 100000)
{
    var tuplesToPush = tuplesToAdd;
    tuplesToAdd = new List<tuple>(10000);
    Monitor.Exit(lockObject);  // releases the lock so other threads can process
    lock (pushLock)  // prevent multiple threads from pushing at the same time
    {
        inspace_.PutAll(tuplesToPush);
    }
}
else
{
    Monitor.Exit(lockObject);
}
```

That way, while one thread is updating the database, the others can be filling the list for the next time around.

---

And after I think about it a bit more, you probably don't even need to use parallel processing for this task. It's likely that the vast majority of your time was being spent by threads waiting on the `Put` call. Using a single thread to batch these and write them in bulk will probably execute much faster than your original solution. The parallel version you decided on will be faster, but I doubt that it will be *hugely* faster.

Comment: private object ConvertToAny(string input)
        {
            double d;
            if (double.TryParse(input, out d))
                return d;

            DateTime dt;
            if (DateTime.TryParse(input, out dt))
                return dt;

            return input;
        }

thats my convert to any method, basically i get an array of objects which could be arbitrarily anything and i have to find out what it is before i insert

Comment: also, if you don't mind i posted a new way that i tried to do it, i didn't test it yet. Can you please advise if its a wise thing to do/

Comment: hey 1 more question when you gave me the way to do it via the que, i was wondering if i can que them but the que executes twice at a time...
so like if i have 4000 tuples after 1 que cycle completes ill have 3998

Comment: @Ramie: I don't see how that's possible. Looking at the code I posted (click the "edited" link at the bottom of the answer), I only see one call to `TryTake` in the loop.